# Parameter passed when calling CONTRACT in michelson

Tags: michelson

When I call the CONTRACT opcode in Michelson, say I have a command like:

`CONTRACT int;`

Does the contract I'm calling this on have to have `int` as a param or could it be something like:

```
parameter Or(Or(string, bool), Or((pair nat int), int));
```

Answer (score 4):

It does need to be exactly an `int`.

Something close to what you describe is probably how multiple entry points for contracts would be supported, though there would be an additional tag to indicate the position of the type in the disjunction.

The technique is known as "sum-type polymorphism".

Comment: great, so this is a feature in the works?

Comment: I haven't heard of anyone working on this, but it's a fun project for an amendment